How to detect absence of recent rows in a single query
Records are being added to table at fixed intervals (e.g. 5 minutes). I'd like to detect when this fails to occur (e.g. no records for the last hour), for each specific id (e.g. temperature sensor id).



id
time
reading




11
2024-01-01 10:30:00
44.5


12
2024-01-01 10:30:00
55.3


11
2024-01-01 10:35:00
45.6


12
2024-01-01 10:35:00
55.6


12
2024-01-01 10:40:00
56.2


12
2024-01-01 10:45:00
54.1



In the example above, sensor 11 stopped logging after 10:35.  I'd like to detect all IDs that recently stopped working, for example:

have relatively recent records (e.g. yesterday or 2 hours ago)
don't have very recent records (e.g. in the last 30 minutes)

So I tried a subquery:
SELECT id,
       Count(1) AS 'Recent Readings'
FROM   tablename
WHERE  TIME > Date_sub(Now(), interval 5 minute)
       AND id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id
                  FROM   tablename
                  WHERE  TIME BETWEEN Date_sub(Now(), interval 10 minute) AND
                                      Date_sub(Now(), interval 5 minute))
GROUP  BY id; 

But this only shows IDs that do have recent readings.
I tried a LEFT OUTER (self)JOIN:
SELECT d1.id,
       Count(d2.id)
FROM   tablename d1
       left outer join tablename d2
                    ON d1.id = d2.id
WHERE  d1.TIME BETWEEN Date_sub(Now(), interval 30 minute) AND
                              Date_sub(Now(), interval 15 minute)
       AND d2.TIME > Date_sub(Now(), interval 15 minute)
GROUP  BY id; 

but this also only shows IDs with recent data.
Adding an Answer
since I can't answer my own closed question. I was able to make this work using the comment from @ValNik
SELECT 
  *, 
  CASE WHEN lasttime > Date_sub(currtime, INTERVAL 30 minute) THEN 'good' ELSE 'stale' end eventtype 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      Max(time) lasttime 
    FROM 
      logs 
    WHERE 
      time > Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 2 day) 
    GROUP BY 
      id
  ) a CROSS 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 5 minute) currtime
  ) t 
WHERE 
  lasttime < currtime

where:

30 minutes (ago) is the threshold between stale and recent
2 day (ago) is how far back to look for readings before the stale threshold (mostly a performance optimisation)
5 minute (ago) defines what current time is.  This could be 0 minute ago as well.

So this query shows a summary of all IDs that had readings in the last 2 days, marked as either having recent (30 minutes ago) readings or not.
The query produces (approximate example):



id
lasttime
currtime
eventtype




11
2024-11-08 14:35:00
2024-11-08 14:55:57
good


12
2024-11-08 14:45:00
2024-11-08 14:55:57
good


10
2024-11-08 08:45:00
2024-11-08 14:55:57
stale




That would be impossible because you do not seem to be storing a date value. Therefore it is impossible to tell if the most recent record is from 1 second ago or from 246060+1 second (yesterday and 1 second) ago .

@Luuk I am using a timestamp type.  I'll edit the question for clarity.  I originally simplified the table because time was what was relevant.

Generate a calendar (complete list of times in needed interval) then CROSS JOIN the IDs list then LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL your data table.

Do you have a separate table listing the ids of things you could have a measure of?

@Akom: When trying to simplify your problem, please never leave out important data/info .....

@Shadow in the subquery example above, the subquery generates the relevant list of ids I care to monitor (it is dynamic).  The fact that some known ID has no records isn't an issue unless it only recently stopped logging them.  I have records from years ago that I don't need to monitor.

Id's that have had readings in the last 24 hours, but not in the last 10 minutes would be: SELECT DISTINCT id FROM   tablename WHERE  TIME BETWEEN Date_sub(Now(), interval 1440 minute) AND Date_sub(Now(), interval 5 minute)) EXCEPT SELECT DISTINCT id FROM   tablename WHERE  TIME BETWEEN Date_sub(Now(), interval 10 minute) AND Date_sub(Now(), interval 5 minute)) (see: EXCEPT)

See examples(https://dbfiddle.uk/iAZutfne)

CASE WHEN lasttime > Date_sub(currtime, INTERVAL 30 minute) THEN 'good' ... is not equal to the result your show with id=11. because the lasttime is more than 4 hours older than currtime

@Luuk I fudged the data a bit so it should be more correct now.  Thanks for the valuable feedback.

@Akom: When changing the (desired)result, please also change the (input)data.
